# Selecting values from a query that are negative in Sybase

Tags: sql, database, sybase, sql-like

Im running the query

```
  SELECT ART_REF FROM tablename WHERE SEMESTER_NUM=28
```

This query returns both positive negative a 0 results in the forms of 8, -2, 0.

how can i just return the values that are negative (-8)?

I've tired using the LIKE operator but with no success.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
SELECT ART_REF 
FROM tablename 
WHERE SEMESTER_NUM=28 
AND ART_REF <0
```